# Single network adapter in Windows to perform DNS queries?

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system

Would it be possible in Windows to set a 'global' list of DNS servers to use? I know they are set per network adapter, but still, I'm curious if there is a chance to achieve that.

I noticed that among the network adapters in my OS there is a Hyper-V Virtual Switch. My understanding of the way it works is very narrow at this point, however. I noticed that for some reason, when I set DNS servers in its configuration, and then run the nslookup command, the DNS servers specified there take precedence over those I configured in my Wi-Fi adapter settings (which actually provides Internet connectivity on my computer). Only when I switch off the virtual adapter are the Wi-Fi adapter DNS servers used.

The reason why I'm asking is that I'm developing an application that is supposed to set DNS servers in Windows. Currently, it does it on all available network adapters, but I'm wondering if there is a more 'elegant' way to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows decides which network adapter to use by its speed, its connectivity and routing metric. DNS servers are 'network global' which means you wifi card uses your wifi's DNS (preferrably).